# Retrieving enum int values

Tags: java, enums

How would you see if there is a value from an enum such as this:

```
public enum Color {

    Blue(1), Red(2), Black(3);

    private int value;

    private Color(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

If you have a List of int as `[1, 3]`?

Something like:

```
boolean isBlue() {
    // check if value of Blue is in the list, return true
    // else false
}
```

Comment: Try writing some code.

Comment: Try adding a List as a parameter to a static method called `isBlue`.

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking or trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a getter for your int-value:

```
public int getIntValue() {
    return this.value;
}
```

Then checking if a value is in a list of Integers, you can do this:

```
final List<Integer> myList = ...
boolean isBlue = myList.contains(Color.Blue.getIntValue());
```

I'm not sure if this i really what you are after though, your question leaves room for interpretation. One word of advice though, using an arbitrary value (like an int) to reference members of an enum is not the way to do it, the extra int connected to each of the enum values adds nothing of value really. Just use a list of `Color`s instead:

```
final List<Color> myList = Arrays.asList(Color.Red, Color.Black, Color.Blue, Color.Red);
final boolean isBlue = myList.contains(Color.Blue);
```

Then it's no room for confusion, the value `Color.Blue` explicitly means `Color.Blue`, while the integer `1` might mean the number of days since yesterday, the smallest integer larger than 0, a map to a Color, or any other enum with the same structure, or some other thing.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution:

```
public enum Color {
  Blue(1),
  Red(2),
  Black(3);


  protected int value;

  private Color(int value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public Boolean IncludedIn(List<Integer> items) {
    return items.contains(value);
  }
}
```

Then just:

```
Color.Blue.IncludedIn(list);
```

Comment: Cool, but could be solved much simpler: isBlue could be: `return this == Blue` for instance..

Answer (score 1):

you can use `values()` to get an array of all your `enum` values, then providing an id you can get corresponding element.

```
        public int getIntValue() {
                return this.value;
        }

        public Color getColorById(int id){
            for(Color value : values()){
                if (value.getIntValue() == id){
                    return value;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate your list using a for loop for instance. For each value, you should check if the value is equal to Color.BLUE.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a method in the enum to check if the sent value is the same as the one from the enum.
See the following:

```
public enum Color {

    Blue(1), Red(2), Black(3);

    private int value;

    private Color(int value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public boolean isCurrentColor(int value){
        return this.value == value;
    }
}
```

To use it, you could do something like this:

```
Color.Blue.isCurrentColor(1); // return True
```